# How to fix .htaccess rewrite not showing CSS

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm running a localhost on my Mac using the native sites, and I can't seem to get .htaccess CSS working. I'm using an index.php page, that is then given url variables to tell which page to display (ex. `index.php?login`). There two issues I'm facing here: The first is that it redirects to a page where my global styles aren't included, and the second is that it shows the homepage instead of my login page.

I've tried navigating to the rewritten site as `localhost/index.php?login`, and all the CSS and HTML displays fine. It's only when I rewrite it as `localhost/login` that it fails. It shows my homepage without any of the styles that should be include from index.php

**Here is my .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteRule ^login$ index.php?login [NC]

</IfModule>
```

**Here is my index.php**

```
//Check for more GET variables.
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$split = explode("?", $url);
if (isset($split[1])) {
    $newvarsarray = explode("&", $split[1]);
    foreach ($newvarsarray as $newvar) {
        $keyandvalue = explode("=", $newvar);
        if (isset($keyandvalue[1])) {
            $_GET[$keyandvalue[0]] = $keyandvalue[1];
        } else {
            $_GET[$keyandvalue[0]] = '';
        }

    }
} else {
    //No additional vars, leave $_GET alone.
}


include_once 'globalheader.html';//Imports styles and things
include_once 'header.html';//Stylized header

//This is the area where we handle the different states of the webpage and import them into here
if (empty($_GET)) {
    //Main homepage
    include_once 'mainpage.html';
} else if (isset($_GET['login'])) {
    //Login page
    include_once 'login.html';
} else if (isset($_GET['register'])) {
    //Register page
    include_once 'register.html';
} else if (isset($_GET['profile'])) {
    //Profile page
}

include_once 'footer.html';//Stylized footer
include_once 'globalfooter.html';//Closes things from globalheader.html
?>
```

I want it to display the correct page with correct CSS instead of seemingly skipping over the entirety of index.php and just using the .html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*tl;dr* you are missing `[OR]`.

A file cannot be "not a file nor a directory" at the same time.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^login$ index.php?login [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That made the login page HTML show correctly, but the global CSS still doesn't want to show up.

Comment: Can't help without seeing what requests are made.

Comment: Here is my global style import:
```<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!--Font imports-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--Global css imports-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/globalstyle.css">
</href>```